# elegant way of filtering data from array of array

Tags: javascript, filter

How to filter data from array of array?.

pls find the explanation in below given example.

We must use `startnumber` and `endnumber` in data query.

```js
const data =  [
{
  "name": "x",
  "points": [
    [100, 50, 1],        //[number, value, bit]       
    [150, 51, 0],
    [170, 52, 1],
    [200, 53, 0]
  ]
},
{
  "name": "y",
  "points": [
    [60, 50, 1],
    [100, 5, 1],
    [150, 6, 0],
    [170, 7, 1],
    [200, 53, 1]
  ]
},
{
  "name": "z",
  "points": [
    [300, 50, 1],
    [350, 51, 0],
    [370, 52, 1],
    [400, 53, 1]
  ]
}
]

// want to find the records with name equal to x & y and number between 100 to 170

const names = ["x", "y"];
const startnumber = 100;
const endnumber = 170;

const finalResult= [];
for(const n of names){
  console.log('name', n);
  console.log('startnumber', startnumber)
  console.log('endnuumber', endnumber)
  const result = data.find(x=>x.name === n)
  
  // how to use startnumber and endnumber here in above line/query ? OR some other elegant solution is required
  
  if(result){
    finalResult.push('result', result);
  }
}

if(finalResult.length){
  console.log(finalResult);
}
```

## Expected result should be

```
[
  {
    "name": "x",
    "points": [
      [100, 50, 1],
      [150, 51, 0],
      [170, 52, 1],
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "y",
    "points": [
      [100, 5, 1],
      [150, 6, 0],
      [170, 7, 1],
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const results = data.filter(elem => !!names.find(name => name == elem.name))
```

Explanation:

1. `data.filter` applies the callback to each element of the array `data`
2. `names.find` applies the callback to each element of the array `names` in order to find a match.
3. `!!` is used because `find` returns an element, so `!!` causes a double negation that turns it into a boolean, the expected return from the `find` callback (its actually not strictly necessary, as `find` returning `undefined` would be coerced to false), but it clarifies the intention.
4. The result is only the elements of `data` that have names properties that match the values in `names`.

```js
const data =  [
{
  "name": "x",
  "points": [
    [100, 50, 1],        //[number, value, bit]       
    [150, 51, 0],
    [170, 52, 1],
    [200, 53, 0]
  ]
},
{
  "name": "y",
  "points": [
    [60, 50, 1],
    [100, 5, 1],
    [150, 6, 0],
    [170, 7, 1],
    [200, 53, 1]
  ]
},

{
  "name": "y",
  "points": [
    [60, 50, 1],
    [200, 53, 1]
  ]
},

{
  "name": "z",
  "points": [
    [300, 50, 1],
    [350, 51, 0],
    [370, 52, 1],
    [400, 53, 1]
  ]
}
]

// want to find the records with name equal to x & y and number between 100 to 170

const names = ["x", "y"];
const startNumber = 100;
const endNumber = 170;

const results = data
  .filter(elem => !!names.find(name => name == elem.name))
  .map(elem => {
    return {
      name: elem.name,
      points: elem.points.filter(point => point[0] >= startNumber && point[0] <= endNumber)
    }
  })
  .filter(elem => elem.points.length > 0)

console.log(results)
```

Comment: you are not considering starnumber and endnumber like me. we must consider them in query.

Comment: You just said you wanted to consider them, but not how.  What's the comparison, and which fields in `points` do they apply too?  Now you have a partial solution, why not try expanding the filter predicate to include the logic you think you need, and amend the post if you still need help?

Comment: 'between' can be interpetted as inclusive or exclusive of the start and end values, but you don't specify whether this is the first element in each tuple.  Be specific.  Computers (and developers) like specific requirements.

Comment: My example has all the details (in form of comments) if you just check it again. Also check  I have given an example of expected result in the end.

Comment: I updated based on what I think is the correct interpretation of your expected output.  It's not clear if you would want the object returned if there are no valid points, so this assumes that's ok.

Comment: This looks almost correct. Yes if points are not found, it should not return that entire object. if you can update otherwise this looks good.

Comment: I added a filter to check for points (and added another input object to prove it).

Answer (score 0):

The task and the two given data structures imply a two folded filter process for each data item.

1. Identifying the data item by its name (from the additionally provided `names` array).
2. Filtering each data item's `points` array by whether a `points` item's first array item (the `number` value) is within a certain number range (which is defined by the additionally provided `startnumber` and `endnumber` values).

Thus a viable approach was to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the provided `data` array by a reducer function which for each `data` item takes care of the above two tasks.

The reducer function's [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) will be kind of a config and/or collector object which features ...

- a `name` lookup (applied as a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance) for the to be explicitly processed `data` items.
- the `startnumber` and `endnumber` range values as `lowerNumber` respectively `upperNumber`.
- and a `result` array where only those `data` items get pushed into which fulfill all requirements.

```js
function collectItemsByNameWhichHavePointsInNumberRange(collector, item) {
  const { nameLookup, lowerNumber, upperNumber, result } = collector;
  let { name, points } = item;

  // ... collect items by name ...
  if (nameLookup.has(name)) {
    points = points
      .filter(([number]) =>
        (number >= lowerNumber) && (number <= upperNumber)
      );

    // ... which (actually do) have points (with)in (a) number range.
    // (according to the above `points` filter result)

    if (points.length >= 1) {
      result
        .push({
          ...item,
          points,
        });
    }
  }
  return collector;
}

const data = [{
  name: "x",
  points: [
  //[number, value, bit]
    [100, 50, 1],
    [150, 51, 0],
    [170, 52, 1],
    [200, 53, 0],
  ],
}, {
  name: "y",
  points: [
    [60, 50, 1],
    [100, 5, 1],
    [150, 6, 0],
    [170, 7, 1],
    [200, 53, 1],
  ],
}, {
  name: "z",
  points: [
    [300, 50, 1],
    [350, 51, 0],
    [370, 52, 1],
    [400, 53, 1],
  ],
}];

const names = ["x", "y"];
const startnumber = 100;
const endnumber = 170;

const { result } = data
  .reduce(collectItemsByNameWhichHavePointsInNumberRange, {
    nameLookup: new Map(names.map(value => [value, value])),
    lowerNumber: startnumber,
    upperNumber: endnumber,
    result: [],
  });

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution:

```
const res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name, points } = curr
  const filteredPoints = points.filter(p => p[0] >= startNumber && p[0] <= endNumber)
  return names.includes(name) && filteredPoints.length > 0 ? acc.concat({ name, points: filteredPoints }) : acc
}, [])
```

Comment: Notice _startNumber_ & _endNumber_ camelCase